# How to get only one value from multiple input text field with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to get value from specific input text field. There are many text field with same name and same class with different values and each input have 1 button. How can i get the value from each one of the fields by clicking on each specific button. Using with Javascript or Jquery? Please guide me.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />


    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try to encapsulate the buttons and inputs with a div
2. from the button event get this (the button)
3. with $(this).closest('div') get to parent and get the next input from there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('div');
    alert(div.find('input').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa"/>
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb"/>
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc"/>
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd"/>
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee"/>
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

Comment: why to go into ocean when you can swim in glass of water .

Comment: I like the vast space of the ocean :) - prev() is also an exellent approach, but depends on dom structure more than I like... just my opinion though...

Comment: I got it. Thanks alot. It's work with your logic. I put my hidden input field into the button div and it's work.

Comment: How can i put that values into array. For example : I click 2nd button the value will put into array and again click on last button i put that value into that existing array but the 1st array should not delete it's look like merge or something. How can i do that bro:?

Comment: use a global variable for that: window.myArray.push(div.find('input').val());

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('.clickme').click(function() {

  alert($(this).prev().val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />


<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
```

1. On click of button use `this` context to get the button clicked.
2. Use `.prev()` to get the previous element which is the input.
3. Use `.val()` to get the value.

Comment: `previous sibling element`

Comment: It's work but I'm sorry. I forgot to type <div> in code. The input text field and Button are not in same <div> bro. In this case, how can I do bro? Help me.. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: can you update the html structure so that i can see how it looks like really then i can give a solution @KyawZinWai

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("input.clickme").click(function () {
   alert($(this).prev('input[name=myvalue]').val());
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be current clicked `button` and `prev('input')` will select above input element. see below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(".clickme").on('click',function(){
         alert($(this).prev('input').val());
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />


    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
```

Comment: I got it bro. Thanks alot.