# Selecting a single input value from an HTML file using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to do a form validation WITHOUT jquery. I have found this code, but I am not sure how to convert it from Jquery to plain Javascript.
I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015023/how-to-get-only-one-value-from-multiple-input-text-field-with-same-name)

```js
$('.clickme').click(function() {

  alert($(this).prev().val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />


<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
```

Any help with this would be amazing. I have multiple forms in one HTML file, all with the same input variables, and I need the functions to only run for when that specific input button is clicked.

Comment: you'd use `document.querySelectorAll('.clickme')` to get a list of buttons, then iterate through the result, and `addEventListener` to each node to handle the click event and alert the previous siblings value

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.clickme').forEach(i=>i.addEventListener('click',()=>alert(i.previousElementSibling.value)));`

Comment: What are you validating? There is nothing a user can enter any data in? There are only some buttons and hidden inputs and oh yeah almost forgot to mention that irritating alert as well.

Answer (score 0):

The below JS code should do the job :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clickme').forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener('click', () => alert(ele.previousElementSibling.value))
});
```

Need to loop through all elements with class "click me" and add a click event to them

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.clickme').forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener('click', () => alert(ele.previousElementSibling.value))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />


<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />

<input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee" />
<input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
```